# Regex to replace repeating characters from the begin

Tags: php, regex

I have the folowing regex code in php that its find and replace all repeating characters.

```
        $parts = explode("@", 'aaabbbddddeeesd@yahoo.com');
        $username = $parts[0];
        $domain = $parts[1];
        $out = preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $username);
        $email = $out . '@' . $domain;

        print_r($email);
```

This code is replacing all repeating characters, but i need only to replace only for the first group from the beginning of the string.

Example aaabbbddddeeesd@yahoo.com i need the output to be abbbddddeeesd@yahoo.com

I have tried different regex but only this was working until now.

Thanks

Comment: Very odd requirement, but you would need to anchor your required replacement character to the beginning of the string: `/^(.)\1+/`

Comment: See the documentation for [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), particularly the `$limit` argument.

Comment: By `first group` do you mean what comes before `@`? So `aaabbbddddeeesd` should become `abdesd`?

Comment: Either `preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $s, 1)` or `preg_replace('/^(.)\1+/', '$1', $s)`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a regex, you can instead extract the first character of the username (using `$username[0]`) and `ltrim()` it off the string, and put 1 occurrence of it back in...

```
$out = $username[0].ltrim($username, $username[0]);
```